# Findbugs report without bug description

Tags: java, findbugs

Findbugs is generating the following report:

```
<BugCollection version="3.0.1" threshold="medium" effort="min">
    <file classname="com.example.MyClass"/>
    <Error/>
    <Project>
    <SrcDir>
        /Users/user/Developer/Service/src/main/java
    </SrcDir>
    <SrcDir>
        /Users/user/Developer/Service/src/test/java
    </SrcDir>
    </Project>
</BugCollection>
```

I already added this to the exclude filter file:

```
<FindBugsFilter>
    <Match>
        <Class name="com.example.MyClass" />
    </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

I can't make findBugs succeed in my project. Someone knows why findBugs is saying that this class has a bug?

Unfortunately I can't post the code of the class. The class is very simple, is just a validation class.

Comment: Just a recommendation on the side spotbugs is the new findbugs

Comment: @SimonSchrottner thanks, I did not know. I will check it ;)